# TypeScript: String manipulate a property/field name

Tags: typescript

I'm building an Nuxt.js billingual Blog with TypeScript. The application consumes data from an REST API. The data is structured like this:

```
{
  "Headline_de": "Mein erster Blogpost",
  "Headline_en": "My first Blogpost",
}
```

Getting the data from the API for one language looks like this:

```
export const mutations = {
  setCurrentBlogpost(state, blogpostId) {
    const currentBlogpost = await axios.get(api + blogpostId);
    
    const normalizedBlogpost = {
      headline: currentBlogpost.Headline_de,
    };
    state.commit('setCurrentBlogpost', currentBlogpost.data);
  }
};
```

Now I want to get the data, depending on which language currently is chosen. I already tried to manipulate the property like this:

```
const headline = 'currentBlogpost.Headline_' + this.$i18n.locale; // prints de or en

export const mutations = {
  setCurrentBlogpost(state, currentBlogpost) {
    const normalizedBlogpost = {
      headline: headline,
    };
    state.currentBlogpost = normalizedBlogpost;
  }
};
```

But now, it just sets the property as a String. Is there a way to manipulate the input properties, for my issue?

Edit: I got it running like this. But I feel like, there is a way simpler way to achieve this.

```
 setCurrentBlogpost(state, currentBlogpost) {

    if (this.$i18n.locale == 'de') {
      const normalizedBlogpost: Blogpost = {
        headline: currentBlogpost.Headline_de,
      };
      state.currentBlogpost = normalizedBlogpost;
    }

    if (this.$i18n.locale == 'en') {
      const normalizedBlogpost: Blogpost = {
        headline: currentBlogpost.Headline_en,
      };
      state.currentBlogpost = normalizedBlogpost;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, you can access properties using strings via [] operator where you state the property name (key), for example, `currentBlogpost.Headline_de` is equivalent to `currentBlogpost["Headline_de"]`.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek wow. this is great. thank you very much! I added an answer, implementing your solution. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right thing to do is to index into `currentBlogpost` via bracket access, like `currentBlogpost[headline]`, where `headline` is either `"Headline_en"` or `"Headline_de"`.

Furthermore, as of TypeScript 4.1, if you use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to represent your `headline` string, you can use a [template literal `const` assertion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40707) to get a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types).  Specifically, the template literal  `` `Headline_${this.$i18n.locale}` as const `` will be evaluated as the type `"Headline_en" | "Headline_de"`:

```
  $i18n = {
    locale: Math.random() < 0.5 ? "de" as const : "en" as const
  }

  method() {
    const currentBlogpost = {
      "Headline_de": "Mein erster Blogpost",
      "Headline_en": "My first Blogpost",
    }
    const headline = `Headline_${this.$i18n.locale}` as const;
    const normalizedBlogpost = {
      headline: currentBlogpost[headline], // <-- this type checks!
     };
  }
```

Before TS4.1, `headline` would only be seen as type `string` by the compiler, which is too wide to use as a property key of `currentBlogpost` without a type assertion:

```
const headline = "Headline_"+this.$i18n.locale; // string
const normalizedBlogpost = {
  headline: currentBlogpost[headline], // error!  No index signature 
};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Zdeněk Jelínek, I could already implement a more efficient solution. I implemented it like this and it works:

```
  setCurrentBlogpost(state, currentBlogpost) {
    const locale = this.$i18n.locale;

    const normalizedBlogpost: Blogpost = {
      headline: currentBlogpost['Headline_' + locale],
    };
    state.currentBlogpost = normalizedBlogpost;
  }
};
```